# need help centering bootstrap carousel image

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am having trouble making the image centered in the slider.

Please see my carousel here
https://wordpress-website-headless-v2-c9jivybjd.vercel.app/

it is created using react-bootstrap with next.js

for centering image I've tried adding to image tag

```
.center-block 
margin: 0 auto
```

to both image and carousel-item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possible Solution

To center `inline` HTML elements, add `text-align` property to `center` to it's parent block element.

Below CSS rule will centre the images in the slider.

```
.carousel-item {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.center-block {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

}

// You can center your carousel image with vanilla CSS like me.